# R fixed effect base

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

Small question, I am running a fixed effect regression on panel data : `reg <- felm(Y ~ X1 + factor(X2) | A + B)`, Y and X1 being continuous variable, X2 being company names but I want to study the coefficients of variables issue. However, by definition one company will be excluded and used as base.

How can I identify which company has been excluded ? How can I choose the base ?

Comment: Please don't use the Rstudio tag when your question has nothing to do with the IDE.

Comment: I believe the first level of `X2` is incorporated into the intercept. so you could change `X2` and specify the order of levels manually, or use the `relevel` function.

Comment: I think you should read the documentation `help('felm')` first on how to correctly specify fixed effects in `lfe::felm()`, looks like you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @jay.sf I have read it quite extensively actually  and there are two possibilities : the old way with factor(X2) or G(X2), or the new way with | A + B like in my example. I thought I could combine both in order to get the coefficients only for X2. Do you think it does not make sense ?

Comment: @jay.sf there is also the possibility to use reg <- felm(Y ~ X1 | X2 + A + B) and then getfe but I only want the coeeficients for X2 not A and B and the main issue remain, how do I know which variable as been use as basis, i.e. is equal to 0 among value taken by X2, right ?